# unity game doesn't run as executable

Tags: unity-game-engine

i've been working on a game in unity in the past few days and now when i run the game as an executable it only shows a skybox and my cursor, but the game doesn't run properly.

it's made for the same os as mine. it doesn't have any errors or warnings. runs perfectly in unity.

i tried changing the rendering settings, the camera, player's settings, performance settings but no difference.

does anyone know what should i try to fix it?

[here is what it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTpcl.png)

[and here is what it is supposed to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtuVx.png)

Comment: Search for the [Player Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) on your device and check if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to take a guess and say you need to add the scene you have in engine to the build settings. You most likely had added the SampleScene to the build settings or have some empty scene as the first scene in the order.

I would first, clear the empty scene you have in the scene list, then add the proper scene. To find this list, hit **File->Build Settings->List is here in the pop up**.

To remove a scene, right-click and hit remove. To add an open scene, select the button `Add Open Scenes` [image: example]

Let me know if your scene preferences fix the build.

Comment: @micuchichu Glad I could help! If it solved your problem you can close the question by clicking on the arrow to the left of the answer. It let's others who have a similar issue know this is the solution that fixed it.